# How to save picture from a form and then display it to the view with Laravel?

Tags: laravel

What I'm trying now is that through a form, I'll save a picture (not in the DB), but I don't know in which folder (public inside the storage ? into the asset/img folder ?).

My 2nd problem is how to display this image.

Right now, I can save a picture inside the `storage/app/public` folder, here is my function :

```
protected function saveFiles($idRecette, $file)
{
    $recette = Recette::where('id_recette',$idRecette)->firstOrFail();
    $path = 'documents/recettes/' . $idRecette . '/' . $recette->titre;
    $fileName = $idRecette.'-'.$recette->titre.'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $file->storeAs($path, $fileName);
}
```

And now, the function which display my homepage :

```
public function accueil_recette(Request $request)
{
  $recette_ALL = Recette::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
  $data = array();
  foreach($recette_ALL as $recette){
     $path = 'documents/recettes/';
     $files = Storage::files($path.$recette->id_recette . '/' . $recette->titre);
     $absolute_path = storage_path('app/'.$files[0]);
     $data[$recette->id_recette] = $absolute_path;   
  }
  return view('admin/recette/admin_liste_recette', [
    'data' => $data
  ]);
}
```

And into my view

```
<img src="{{ $data[$recette->id_recette] }}" alt="" width="140" height="100">
```

Then, when I go to the site and do `inspect element`, I have this :

```
<img src="C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\storage\app/documents/recettes/45/Test name/45-Test name.jpg">
```

If I try this path into a folder, it'll open my picture.

But still, no picture is displayed on my page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`storage_path` returns an absolute path to your storage, what you need is `\Storage::url` which returns a URL

But first, ensure you have a symbolic link to `storage/app/public` inside `public` directory, by running artisan command below:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Then:

```
public function accueil_recette(Request $request)
{
  $recette_ALL = Recette::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
  $data = array();
  foreach($recette_ALL as $recette){
     $path = 'documents/recettes/';
     $files = Storage::files($path.$recette->id_recette . '/' . $recette->titre);
     
     //I changed storage_path to Storage::URL
     // Thus will give you `storage/documents/recettes/45/Test name/45-Test name.jpg`
     $data[$recette->id_recette] = \Storage::url($files[0]);   
  }
  return view('admin/recette/admin_liste_recette', [
    'data' => $data
  ]);
}
```

NB:
Ensure the uploaded files/directories exists inside `storage/app/public` directory

Example:
`yourproject/storage/app/public/documents/recettes/45/Test name/45-Test name.jpg`

Comment: First of, thank you for your anwser. When I do `dd($data)`, I have this : `array:1 [▼
  48 => "/storage/app/public/documents/recettes/48/test again"]` Somethig else, there is no extension inside the path (png,jpg...). So nothing is shown inside the view (I have this path inside my view `/storage/app/public/documents/recettes/{$recette->id_recette}/{$recette->titre}`. If I replace it with `$path = 'app/public/documents/recettes/'.$recette->id_recette.'/'.$recette->titre;` I have this in my view : `/storage/app/public/documents/recettes/49/aaaaaaaaa` still no extension

Comment: I updated my answer. storage_path returns a full path, what you need is Storage::url

Comment: I've done this : `$path = 'app/public/documents/recettes/'; $files = Storage::files($path.$recette->id_recette . '/' . $recette->titre); dd($files); $data[$recette->id_recette] = \Storage::url($files[0]); ` but the `dd` return an empty array `[]` and the error is `ErrorException Undefined offset: 0`

Comment: Here is a pastebin, since its a mess in the comments : https://pastebin.com/ttRgj9WJ

Comment: I've discover why it wasn't working. I put back `$path = 'documents/recettes/';` and its working. But my picture does not show up.. I also added `app/` inside mythis `$data[$recette->id_recette] = Storage::url('app/'.$files[0]);`. In my view, I have the correct path `/storage/app/documents/recettes/53/je test/53-je test.jpg` but still no picture. Since its not inside the `public` folder its not working, isn't it? I also did `php artisan storage:link` inside my `laravelProject`

Comment: Remove /app/ from the url

Comment: php artisan storage:link is very important before storage url will work

Comment: Still nothing... In my view I have this `/storage/documents/recettes/56/zazzz/56-zazzz.jpg` and my controller : `$path = 'documents/recettes/';
            $files = Storage::files($path.$recette->id_recette.'/'. $recette->titre);
            $data[$recette->id_recette] = Storage::url($files[0]); ` 
There is a part of the path that is not present, the `app` between `storage` and `documents`

Comment: This `/storage/documents/recettes/56/zazzz/56-zazzz.jpg` looks good. can you check if the file exists in this path. Are you using Linux or Windows, Did you run  `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: the path is not looking good since there is no `app`. The proper path is `storage\app\documents\recettes\58\test123\58-test123.jpg`. Inside my `config/filessystems.php` I've this : 
    `'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'), ] `. Does that means my `php artisan storage:link` is working ?

Comment: check for symbolic link in your `public` directory, where you have index.php, we can have a zoom session if you don't mind

Comment: I have the `storage` folder inside it. But there is only `storage\documents\recettes` inside it, no folder with the name of the picture nor with the id. Should I change my function `saveFiles` to save inside it ?

Comment: StoreAs should work. If you can not find files uploaded,

Comment: yes but `storeAs` is saving my pictures there `myProject\storage\app\documents\recettes\58\test123` but not there `myProject\public\storage\documents\recettes`

Comment: do you have the right permissions on storage

Comment: How can I know that please ?

Comment: Are you using windows or Linux

Comment: Lets speak in the chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228277/discussion-between-balaure-and-emeka-mbah).

Comment: Please accept my answer if it resolved your issue